# PHP/HTML Showing selected option in dropdown from sql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wasn't sure how to title my question, I'm basically asking if anyone knows a better way to approach this. I'm using this function below to show which option is pulled from the DB, I'm wondering if there is a more compact way or better way to do this other than elseif each ID

```
function access_option($access)
{
    if ($access == 0)
    {
        echo '<option value="0" selected>Member</option>
        <option value="1">Streamer</option>
        <option value="2">Moderator</option>
        <option value="3">Manager</option>
        <option value="4">Administrator</option>
        <option value="5">Senior Administrator</option>';
    }
    elseif ($access == 1)
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Member</option>
        <option value="1" selected>Streamer</option>
        <option value="2">Moderator</option>
        <option value="3">Manager</option>
        <option value="4">Administrator</option>
        <option value="5">Senior Administrator</option>';
    }
    elseif ($access == 2)
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Member</option>
        <option value="1">Streamer</option>
        <option value="2" selected>Moderator</option>
        <option value="3">Manager</option>
        <option value="4">Administrator</option>
        <option value="5">Senior Administrator</option>';
    }
    elseif ($access == 3)
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Member</option>
        <option value="1">Streamer</option>
        <option value="2">Moderator</option>
        <option value="3" selected>Manager</option>
        <option value="4">Administrator</option>
        <option value="5">Senior Administrator</option>';
    }
    elseif ($access == 4)
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Member</option>
        <option value="1">Streamer</option>
        <option value="2">Moderator</option>
        <option value="3">Manager</option>
        <option value="4" selected>Administrator</option>
        <option value="5">Senior Administrator</option>';
    }
    elseif ($access == 5)
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Member</option>
        <option value="1">Streamer</option>
        <option value="2">Moderator</option>
        <option value="3">Manager</option>
        <option value="4">Administrator</option>
        <option value="5" selected>Senior Administrator</option>';
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with less repetition using ternary operators:

```
function access_option($access)
{
    echo '<option value="0"'.($access == 0 ? ' selected' : '').'>Member</option>';
    echo '<option value="1"'.($access == 1 ? ' selected' : '').'>Streamer</option>';
    echo '<option value="2"'.($access == 2 ? ' selected' : '').'>Moderator</option>';
    echo '<option value="3"'.($access == 3 ? ' selected' : '').'>Manager</option>';
    echo '<option value="4"'.($access == 4 ? ' selected' : '').'>Administrator</option>';
    echo '<option value="5"'.($access == 5 ? ' selected' : '').'>Senior Administrator</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful and what I was looking for

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the values, which are held in an array, and set the selected value dynamically. This method makes it easy to add/remove options in the future by adjusting the array -

```
function access_option($access)
{
    $options = ["Member", "Streamer", "Moderator", "Manager", "Administrator", "Senior Administrator"];
    foreach($options as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'"'.($key==$access ? ' selected' : '').'>'.$value.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: i like this solution

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operators will reduce the size of it as mentioned as another answer. You can also use the switch statement. Similar to if and elseif but easier and will reduce your code.

Example:

```
<?php
function access_option($access)
{
 switch ($access) {
    case 0: echo "access equals 0";
    case 1: echo "access equals 1";
    case 2: echo "access equals 2";
 }
}
?>
```